# How to get the object of radio button from id in android?

Tags: android, object, radio-button

I have RadioButton in my java class like this.

```
 RatioButton rad1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb1);
```

In have an id for that radiobutton as R.id.rb1 in my .xml file. I know in java class we can create an object for my radio button and assigned it with id. Now my question is can i get the object of radio button object (rad1)? Can anybody tell me how to get it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: already you got that object by R.id.rb1...What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: i want get rad1 which is radiobutton object that i declared in my coding by giving R.id.rb1

Answer (score 0):

rad1 is the object which is a reference to the RadioButton you used in your xml.
You can access the XML's radiobutton in Java class with this help of this object(rad1).

If you want Something else then please elaborate your question.